# i can't figure out why there is no output on my screen for this simple stack implementation using array in c language

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct stack{
    int size;
    int* ptr;
    int top;
};
int isfull(struct stack* a){
    if (a->top==a->size)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int isempty(struct stack* a){
     if (a->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
        }
}

int main()
{
    struct stack* A;
    A->size = 10;
    A->top = -1;
    A->ptr = (int *)malloc(A->size*sizeof(int));

    if(isempty(A)){
        printf("Stack is empty");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

there should be "Stack is empty" on output window, but instead it is blank,
there is no compilation error.
i am stuck on this for hours please help me out here.
i have tried getch() method also it does not help.
i use vscode.
thank you.

Comment: `struct stack* A;` does not allocate RAM, you have a pointer to nothing and then you're writing to it. `malloc` it first. `struct stack* A = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(*A));`

Comment: thanks Geoffrey it really worked , thanks alot.

Comment: No problems, however, I suggest you use the method @Jabberwocky shows below and allocate it on the stack as a local (note the lack of a `*`). Also if using `malloc` don't forget to `free` later so you don't end up with a memory leak.

Comment: thanks alot buddy. i will keep that in mind.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem but the way you use `top` will give problems later. I don't want to give a 'definitive solution' but a way to check for yourself. Namely "go through the edgecases". Make some little drawings if you wish and check 'nothing', 'one' and 'more' cases. What if size == 0 and top == ?. What if size = 1 and top == -1 or top == 0, can top ever be == 1... what if size == 2 what values can top have -1, 0, 1, 2? And how will it behave when adding new values / checking if stack is empty or full. You will get it once you try. Gl & HF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` should probably not be a pointer and you probably want this:

```
int main()
{
  struct stack A;

  A.size = 10;
  A.top = -1;
  A.ptr = malloc(A.size * sizeof(int));

  if (isempty(&A)) {
    printf("Stack is empty");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same :)... ideally should be freeing `A.ptr` too before termination though.

Answer (score 0):

when you declare a struct pointer

```
struct stack* A;
```

you used it without allocating memory and assigning that memory to 'A'.  this line should solve it.

```
A = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
```

Answer (score -2):

I didn't go through the whole code as I saw top being compared to the size. I think top is an index, so it will start from 0. While size will start from 1.
May be you are missing by 1.

Comment: Perhaps you should have, nothing will work if he doesn't malloc `*A`

Comment: I think he wanted to write struct stack A. Then he should have used a pointer to it.

Comment: You're clearly a new SO user so I will explain. You're getting downvoted on this because you provided not only a wrong answer but a guess. The words "I think" and stating you "didn't go through the whole code" should have told you that you should not be posting an answer.

Comment: That's not the problem here, and it is perfectly valid to start with an index of -1 for an _empty_ stack. And a size of 0 is also a good solution for an empty stack as it contains 0 elements.

Comment: @Geoffrey yes sir, This is my first post. And I understand the answer should be downvoted. i should have posted in comments rather then posting an answer. please accept my apologies.